# USB idproduct and idvendor

Tags: usb, registry, windows-embedded-compact, rndis

I am very new to USB interfacing and i am trying to build an application for WINCE 2013 device. In my device, one vendor's (let suppose 'X') VID and PID are using for USB mass storage device class.

Now, i have specific use case where communication should be built on USB rndis class. For this communication purpose we are using microsoft generic rndis driver as is (not a custom one). So, can i use the X's VID and PID(which i am using for MASS STORAGE class now) for the Rndis class too or need to purchase a new one again. I know that i can use any VID and PID during development stage but i need VID and PID's for production devices.

Or can i go with Microsoft VID, PID and compatible id's compatible for Microsoft generic rndis driver by changing only the Serial Number for devices?

Please suggest and thanks in advance! :-)

(Do let me know if the query is too vague to understand.)

Comment: If the RNDIS driver is anything like Microsoft's `usbser.sys` driver, it won't discriminate against devices based on their USB vendor ID or product ID.  Your device should use your own vendor ID, not Microsoft's.  You might have to supply an INF file to tell Windows which driver to use for your device.  You should really test that your firmware/driver/software set up will work instead of relying on StackOverflow answers; don't you have a machine you can test it on?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find a definitive answer, but maybe we'll be able to extrapolate from [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fa1eeca-a5f8-41c2-a596-08ae8f3a6daf/usb-rndis-driver-and-driver-signing?forum=winembplatdev) by a Microsoft MVP (emphasis mine):

> (...) you don't have to change MS's VID/PID anymore if
>   you use USB RNDIS **to use ActiveSync**.
>
> Here's the official response from
>   Microsoft on this subject (as asked by a fellow MVP regarding a client
>   who had the same issue):
>
> Question: Should they use the Microsoft PIDVID or create their own? If
>   they create their own, it means modifying the current .inf file and
>   therefore this means the driver will be unsigned and therefore may not
>   be able to be installed. In the past the Microsoft PIDVID gave warnings
>   to not use this. Now in 6.0 the warnings do not appear.
>
> Answer: The answer is exactly the same as for Windows Mobile: For
>   ActiveSync usage, YES, you can use Microsoft's VID & PID for your scenario.
>
> This is a change from documentation which says to get your own PID &
>   VID. Contrary to what the sample Registry file says, the OEM should ship
>   the device using Microsoft's VID & PID for USB-Serial ActiveSync client.
>   The latest OEM documentation confirms this (...)

Now, since you don't specifically mention ActiveSync, my understanding is that the above probably does *not* apply to your use case, which again means you will have to use your own VID and PID.

If you already own a VID/PID combination, I don't see any (legal) issues using this with RNDIS as well. It is the same device after all, and the USB host would load one of two different class (not custom) drivers to communicate with the device.

However, if you use your own VID/PID you will have to either

1. supply a signed INF file to end-users that contains your custom VID/PID, or
2. instruct users to manually select the RNDIS driver when your device is connected to the PC for the first time